# Why a reference is said to be unchanged in C++ primer 5th, how ever this following code works?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

In the book, we explain that there is no way to make a reference refer to different object, how ever the following code works for c++ 11.

```
int i1 = 1, i2 = 0;
int &ri = i1;
ri = i2;
```

Comment: What do you think `ri = i2;` does?

Comment: What would `ri = 7;` do? Same thing.

Comment: `ri` _refers_ to `i1`, meaning that when you write `ri = i2;`, you effectively achieve `i1 = i2;`.

Comment: A reference in C++ is more like an alias.  When an argument is passed to a function by reference, it is _as if_ the function was working directly on the argument.  (The details of how a reference does its magic is an implementation detail.  Most likely done as a pointer, under-the-covers, but that implementation detail is not exposed or part of the standard.)

Answer (score 5):

`ri` doesn't change what it's pointing to, it changes the value of what it's pointing to. So if you print the value if `i1` you will see it is now equal to `0`, and if you change the value of `i2` you will see it doesn't affect `ri`:

```
int main() {
    int i1 = 1, i2 = 0;
    int& ri = i1;
    ri = i2; // i1 == 0
    std::cout << "i1 " << i1 << "\n";
    i2 = 5;
    std::cout << "i2 " << i2 << "\n";
}
```

And the output is

> i1 0
>   i2 5

Answer (score 2):

> Why a reference is said to be unchanged in C++ primer 5th, how ever this following code works?

Because it is possible to change the value of an integer. And that is what `ri = i2` does. The reference is unaffected; it still refers to the same object. The value of the referred object is affected. The result is same as if you had written `i1 = i2`.

Answer (score 2):

To get a better understanding,  try this:

```
int i1 = 1, i2 = 0;

int &ri = i1;          // ri refers to i1 and this won't change afterwards
cout << ri <<endl;     // same value as i1, so 1
i1 = 3; 
cout << ri <<endl;     // still same value as i1, but now it's 3
ri = 5; 
cout << i1 <<endl;     // same value as ri since both name refer to the same variable, so 5

ri = i2;               // ri still refers to i1, but copies value of i2 in it
cout << i1<<endl;      // i1 was overwritten through ri
ri = 7;  
cout << i1 << endl     // i1 was overwritten again through ri
     <<i2 <<endl;      // but i2 stays unchanged, since ri does not refer to it.
```